# Airgeddon is not giving the handshake, despite it seems that it capture it

Tags: wifi, parrotsec, handshake

I was using few times Parrot OS live booted from RAM or USB as well. I have started the learning path with the basics, so I tried to **grab handshake of my own wifi networks**.

**I succeded few times**, but now I am in problem.

I am choosing the network that handshake would be taken of and then the method of taking handshake (no matter which one of the three I choose) the result is always same. The small window is opened in the top right screen. **After several seconds appears the string `][WPA handshake: BSSID]`. This normally was the success** and I was prompted to give the path for the handshake. I am doing completely **same steps on same parrot os usb and for the same network as before** and now it doesn't give me handshake.

[image]

Insted there is a failure like below.

[image]

**What is going on and how to fix it?**

If I choosed wrong stack-exchange please point me where should I post my question. Regards

Comment: any help? where Can I ask for this?